# bits 16 and bits 32 in nasm

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, disassembly

test.asm:

```
org 0100h
[BITS 16]
mov eax, 0
[BITS 32]
mov eax, 0
```

Then compile and disassemble as follows:

`nasm test.asm -o test.com`

`ndisasm -o 0x0100 test.com`

Result:

```
00000100  66B800000000      mov eax,0x0
00000106  B80000            mov ax,0x0
00000109  0000              add [bx+si],al
```

So from the result, we can see that `[BITS 16]` use `eax`, `[BITS 32]` use `ax`, why? Should the result turn over?

Comment: Isn't it just ndisasm that is confused when you mix 16- and 32-bit code? `B800000000` would be `mov eax, 0` in 32-bit mode.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A .com file is basically a binary chunk of code (and data). It does not have any high-level info about its internals. So `ndisasm` can't tell whether it should disassemble in 16-bit or 32-bit mode and it defaults to 16-bit. This does produce the correct result for the "BITS 16" part, as you can see, but the following code has been assembled as 32-bit code but `ndisasm` is still disassembling it as 16-bit, thus the garbage output. If you specify "-b 32" you'll see the *second* part being disassembled properly:

```
>ndisasm.exe -b 32 -o100h test.com
00000100  66B80000          mov ax,0x0
00000104  0000              add [eax],al
00000106  B800000000        mov eax,0x0
```

In short, `ndisasm` does *what you tell it to*, not what you *want it to*. Because of the .com format there's no way for it to tell whether a given bunch of bytes is 16-bit or 32-bit code, or even just data, so you need to help it.